# divide two columns group by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to divide two columns revenue from df1 and revenue from df2 grouping by id and date.

I did something like this, but am getting an error.

```
df.groupby(['id','date']).agg({'ratio': lambda L: df1['revenue'].div(df2['revenue'])})
```

**data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x1', 'x2'],
           'date':['2021-01-02',
           '2021-01-03'],
       'revenue':[50,10]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x2', 'x1', 'x1'],
            'date':['2021-01-03','2021-01-02', '2021-01-01'],
       'revenue':[100,100, 200]})
```

**expected output**

```
     id     date    ratio

0   x2  2021-01-03      0.5

1   x1  2021-01-02      0.1

2   x1  2021-01-01      0
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: KeyError: 'ratio' @mcsoini

Comment: Please share your data with expected output.

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani please see my edits. Thank you

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani i did **df2['ratio'] = df1['revenue']/df2['revenue']**

Comment: I think `0.1` with `0.5` is swapped.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join by columns `id` and `date`, then divide and replace missing values by `0`:

```
s = df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left')['revenue_y'].div(df2['revenue'])
df2['ratio']  = s.fillna(0)
print (df2)
   id        date  revenue  ratio
0  x2  2021-01-03      100    0.1
1  x1  2021-01-02      100    0.5
2  x1  2021-01-01      200    0.0
```

Comment: thank you !! can you explain more your proposition please? should we add groupby id and date here  **div(df2['revenue'])**

Comment: @biwia - I think not, because `merge` is use necessary here. If use `groupby` there is no match by `id, date`

Comment: how should i print the result of **df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left')['revenue_y']** please?

Comment: @biwia - `print(df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left')['revenue_y'])` ?

Comment: @biwia - For new column `df2['df1_revenue'] = df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left')['revenue_y']`

Comment: i have to say that i was not gotting the expected results when running on big data. so i did something with adding a resulting dataframe                                                                   **`df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left')
df3['ratio'] = df3['revenue_y'].div(df3['revenue_x'])
df3['ratio'] = df3['ratio'].fillna(0) `**

Comment: @biwia - So my solution not working, but `df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['id','date'], how='left') df3['ratio'] = df3['revenue_y'].div(df3['revenue_x']) df3['ratio'] = df3['ratio'].fillna(0)` working well ?

Comment: @biwia - One thing - what is length both DataFrames -  `print (len(df2.index))` and `print (len(df3.index))` ? It is same?

Comment: 296182 and 292154